# Java call generic function on generic object

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, functional-interface

I want to have a method like this

```
<T> void callFuncOnObj(T obj, Runnable r) {
   obj.r();
   //or
   r.runOnTheInstance(obj);
}
```

that may be used something like this (ignoring exceptions)

```
   callFuncOnObj(System.in, InputStream::close);
```

Obviously, `Runnable` doesn't support this.  Apparently, the type of `InputStream::close` is just Object, so how can it be used or even cast so that a generic instance may call it?

The most obvious alternative I can think of is accepting a `Method` and dealing with `IllegalArgumentException` if it doesn't apply,

```
void callFuncOnObj(Object obj, Method m) {
   try{
      m.invoke(obj);
   }catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
      ...
   }...
}
```

Is there a good way to do this with generic instances and generic functions on those instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a couple of problems. First, `InputStream.close()` throws an exception, so it can't be passed as a `Runnable`. You can either convert the method reference to a lambda containing a try/catch block, or create a custom parallel interface that allows exceptions:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CustomRunnable {
    void run() throws Exception;
}
```

The other issue is that `Runnable` doesn't accept any arguments. You can pass an [instance method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#:%7E:text=compareByAge%0AMethodReferencesExamples%3A%3AappendStrings-,Reference%20to%20an%20instance%20method%20of%20a%20particular%20object,-containingObject%3A%3AinstanceMethodName) instead of passing the object separately:

```
void callFuncOnObj(CustomRunnable r) {
   r.run();
}
```

Called like this:

```
callFuncOnObj(System.in::close);
```

Or you can accept the object with a `Consumer` (or in this case, a similar interface that allows exceptions) and combine them like this:

```
<T> void callFuncOnObj(T obj, CustomConsumer<T> c) {
   c.accept(obj);
}
```

And then your original call would work:

```
callFuncOnObj(System.in, InputStream::close);
```

Comment: So the type of `InputStream::close` is `Consumer<InputStream>`?

Comment: @user21583770 That's correct.

Comment: No, that is not correct. `InputStream::close` does not have any type, and therefore, is illegal java code. __Unless__, from context, a relevant type can be determined for which `InputStream::close` _would_ fit. So, `Object o = InputStream::close;` is invalid. But, `Consumer<InputStream> o = InputStream::close;` does work. __Because__ the type of `o` tells the compiler how to interpret the expression being assigned to it. lambdas and method refs are typed 'outside-in'.

Comment: `SOMETYPE x = InputStream::close();` works if SOMETYPE is a functional type (an interface that defines only one non-defaulted method that isn't already in `j.l.Object`), and the one method it defines has a signature that 'works', e.g. `void foo(Object o)` or `void foo(InputStream o)`. `Consumer<InputStream>` is merely one of an infinite number of such types.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Right. I thought OP was asking in the context of this assignment. Thanks for clarifying.